# Grunt tarea estableciendo options?

Tags: javascript

Quiero configurar una tarea donde pueda establecer 2 parámetros y no tener que establecerlos en la consola cada vez que la llamo.

Esto es lo que ejecuto en la consola:

```
grunt serve:proxy --proxyServer=8.8.8.8 --proxyPort=9999
```

Y estas son las tareas que he intentando declarar pero ninguna funciona:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve:dev', 'serve:proxy:proxyServer=8.8.8.8:proxyPort=9999');

grunt.registerTask('serve:dev_', '', function(obj){

    console.log ( grunt.config ('proxyServer')); //undefine
    console.log ( grunt.option ('proxyServer')); //undefine

    grunt.option('proxyServer', '8.8.8.8');
    grunt.option('proxyPort', 9999);

    console.log ( grunt.config ('proxyServer')); //undefine
    console.log ( grunt.option ('proxyServer')); //8.8.8.8

    grunt.task.run('serve:proxy');
});
```

En el log puede ver que siempre se queda con la configuración por defecto:

```
Proxy created for: /my_path to localhost:3000
Proxy created for: /my_path to localhost:3000
Proxy created for: /my_path to localhost:3000
Proxy created for: /my_path to localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré una solución, estaba almacenando los parámetros en el lugar equivocado, lo correcto es:

```
  grunt.registerTask('serve:proxy:dev', 'proxy to dev', function (){

//   grunt serve:proxy --proxyServer=8.8.8.8 --proxyPort=9999
    grunt.config.set('config.proxyServer', '8.8.8.8');
    grunt.config.set('config.proxyPort', '9999');
    grunt.task.run('serve:proxy');


  });
```

---

Los parámetros (proxyServer y proxyPort) se usaban con una template de grunt (<%=config.proxyServer%> y <%=config.proxyPort%>).

Aunque establezcas los parámetros a nivel de config:
    grunt.config('proxyServer', '8.8.8.8');
    grunt.config('proxyPort', 9999);

Después se usan a nivel de config.config:

```
grunt.config.
             proxyServer: 8.8.8.8 <-- este no es 
             proxyPort: 9999      <-- este tampoco
             config.
                    proxyServer: 8.8.8.8 <-- ESTE SI 
                    proxyPort: 9999      <-- ESTE TAMBIEN
```

Mas información: https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config
PD: hice un console.log(grunt.config) para ver objeto de configuración